# Select element with specific tag name but with any namespace by using javascript querySelector

Tags: javascript, mathml, javascript-namespaces

How can i use document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll to get specific tag with any **namespace**.

I cannot use JQuery or any other library.

Ex

```
<mml:math>
    <mml:row>
    </mml:row>
  </mml:math>
<math style="display:none;">
  <mrow>
   <msup>
     <mfenced>
       <mrow>
         <mi>a</mi>
         <mo>+</mo>
         <mi>b</mi>
       </mrow>
     </mfenced>
     <mn>2</mn>
   </msup>
 </mrow>
</math>

 var tags = ['math:not([style*="display:none"])','mml\\:math:not([style*="display:none"])'];
                              document.querySelectorAll(mathmlVisibleTag.join()).length
```

Here user can use any namespace.
I have tried `'*\\:math:not([style*="display:none"])'` in querySelectorAll but it didn't worked.

Regards

Comment: You want to select any element which *doesn't* have display none?

Comment: @TKoL Yes. I want to find any visible math element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the only querySelectorAll. Maybe the best option is something like this:

```
function isVisible(e) {
    return !!( e.offsetWidth || e.offsetHeight || e.getClientRects().length );
}

var tags = document.querySelectorAll('*'); // change this to be more specific
var visibleMaths = [].slice.call(tags).filter(function (tag) {
    return tag.nodeName.search(/math/i) >= 0 &&
             isVisible(tag);
});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/L88fx2ww/)

Comment: Isn't `Array.from(tags)` preferrable to `[].slice.call(tags)`? [This resource](https://jsperf.com/array-from-vs-array-prototype-slice) says it's a lot faster, but apart from being faster it's also more obvious what it's doing.

Comment: I don't know if it is faster or not...it really depends on the browser. Anyway, I wrote it as an example, I didn't look at the details :)

Answer (score -3):

You just missed space, this one works fine:

```
document.querySelectorAll('math :not([style*="display:none"])');
```

Comment: @ePetkvo Above one is  also working fine. I want to select math tag which could have any namespace.